# Use Darcula LAF in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, look-and-feel

I have the [Darcula LAF](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62424/darcula-laf-for-netbeans) installed in Netbeans, and it is functional. It modifies the way the IDE looks as well as the way applications look in the 'Preview Design' popup and the GUI Builder.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj7kJ.png) is an example.

However, the look and feel doesn't stay when running the application.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40pLt.png) is an example.

The installed look and feels are listed using this code

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            System.out.println(info.getName());
        }
```

Clearly, the Darcula LaF is installed. However, it isn't showing up as installed to the compiler. Is there a way for me to get the LaF for the compiler while maintaining the Netbeans module?

I have looked on the [download page](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62424/darcula-laf-for-netbeans), the [GitHub page](https://github.com/bulenkov/Darcula), and even [Geertjan's blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/setting_up_darcula_in_netbeans) for information on the subject, have found nothing related to this.

I'm sure that I'm missing something painfully obvious. Not setting the look and feel has it default to metal, and using the OS default look and feel doesn't resolve the issue, either.

All help is appreciated, I apologize if this is incorrectly formatted.

EDIT: It is only set to Nimbus in the code for clarity. Have some screenshots of how it reacts when it isn't set to Nimbus. It defaults to metal.
I have removed the code that sets it to Nimbus before, and it uses Metal. http://prntscr.com/bte2xg
I have set it to use "Darcula" rather than Nimbus in the past, and yet it still uses Metal. http://prntscr.com/bte2b5

I have set it to use "darcula-1.0.0" rather than Nimbus in the past, and yet it still uses Metal. http://prntscr.com/bte3nh

I have set it to use "darcula-1.0.0.jar" rather than Nimbus in the past, and yet it still uses Metal.  http://prntscr.com/bte42m

I have set it to use "com.bulenkov.darcula" in the past, and yet it still uses Metal. http://prntscr.com/bte3du

I merely left Nimbus in there for the sake of it appearing in something presentable.

Comment: In your code, you're telling Java to use Nimbus -- so why would you expect it to use the Darcula L&F? It matters not if it's installed -- it's what your code is telling Java that matters.

Comment: It is only set to Nimbus for clarity. See the edit to the main post to see what happens when that code isn't in it. I thought that you would enjoy looking at an example of something other than Metal, but since it appears not, I have attached screenshots that don't feature the code setting it to Nimbus.

Answer (score 6):

Including the jar file found [here](https://github.com/Revivius/nb-darcula/raw/master/lib/com/bulenkov/darcula/1.0.0/darcula-1.0.0.jar) in the classpath and using this code

```
BasicLookAndFeel darcula = new DarculaLaf();
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(darcula);
```

solved the issue. I apologize for my own idiocy.

Comment: To add it via Gradle, add this to the dependencies section: 
compile group: 'com.bulenkov', name: 'darcula', version: '2018.2'

Answer (score 2):

```
    for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
        System.out.println(info.getName());
        if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Your code is telling Java to use Nimbus -- so Nimbus it will use regardless of any other L&F that is installed. If you want to use another L&F, then get rid of the line that installs Nimbus L&F and replace it with yours.

Answer (score 2):

add darcula.jar in your Library;
then import com.bulenkov.darcula.DarculaLaf in your source file
after that

```
for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    System.out.println(info.getName());
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new DarculaLaf());
        break;
    }
}
```

make sure your ticked "Copy Dependented Libraries" in your Project Properties-> Packaging Tab.